# Factory Pattern & overrideable method call in constructor

Tags: java, factory-pattern

I took the factory pattern example from this link: http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/23/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java/

However when I copy the code into my own IDE I'm getting a warning saying that I have an overrideable method call in my constructor. I understand what this means, I just thought that the factory pattern was supposed to solve this problem? Is the tutorial flawed? Should I be doing something different?

I've only included one of the car types just to save on the amount of code I'm pasting:

Class `Car`:

```
package FactoryPattern;

public abstract class Car {



    public Car(CarType model){
        this.model = model;
        arrangeParts();
    }

    private void arrangeParts(){
        //Do one time processing herer
    }

    //Do subclass level processing in this method

    protected abstract void construct();
    private CarType model = null;
    public CarType getModel(){
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel (CarType model){
        this.model = model;
    }


}
```

Class `CarFactory`:

```
package FactoryPattern;


public class CarFactory {

    public static Car buildCar(CarType model){
        Car car = null;
        switch (model) {
            case SMALL:
                car = new SmallCar();
                break;
            case SEDAN:
                car = new SedanCar();
                break;
            case LUXURY:
                car = new LuxuryCar();
                break;
            default:
                //throw an exception
                break;        
        }
        return car;
    }    
}
```

Class `FactoryPattern`:

```
package FactoryPattern;

public enum CarType {

    SMALL, SEDAN, LUXURY

}

package FactoryPattern;

public class LuxuryCar extends Car {

    LuxuryCar(){
        super(CarType.LUXURY);
        construct();
    }

    @Override
    protected void construct(){
        System.out.println("Building Luxury Car");
    }

}
```

Class `CarFactoryTest`:

```
package FactoryPattern;

public class CarFactoryTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CarFactory.buildCar(CarType.SMALL);
        CarFactory.buildCar(CarType.SEDAN);
        CarFactory.buildCar(CarType.LUXURY);
    }

}
```

Comment: Honestly, find another tutorial. This one looks like it was written by a bookreader, not a programmer.

Comment: Switching on an enum is a poor practice that can lead for fragile code that is difficult to maintain.  Favor using enum constant-specific methods instead.

Answer (score 1):

The warning comes from here

```
LuxuryCar(){
    super(CarType.LUXURY);
    construct();
}
```

The `construct()` method is `protected` and therefore can be overriden in subclasses of `LuxuryCar`. If an unknowing developer overrides the method and tries to use fields that haven't been initialized yet in the parent class, a lot of things can go bad. That's why the IDE is warning you.

For example,

```
public class LuxuryCar extends Car {
    protected Televesion tv;

    LuxuryCar(){
        super(CarType.LUXURY);
        construct(); // will call the overriden method in the sub class
    }

    @Override
    protected void construct(){
        tv = new Television();
    }
}

public class BetterLuxuryCar extends LuxuryCar {
    BetterLuxuryCar(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void construct(){
        tv.upgrade(); // oops NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Note that a method like `construct()` seems like it belongs in the Factory itself. Also, the `Car` class doesn't need a `CarType` field, the sub type already knows what type it is.

Comment: Thanks, I completely understand why I'm being warned about the overrideable method. I was just under the impression that the factory method implemented correctly shouldn't have this warning, so I'm wondering how I would alter the code to make it correct?

Should I move the println of "building Luxury Car" into the Factory and replace the LuxuryCar method call?

Comment: @Killian Yes, you will usually want to move methods that do any preparation to the factory and any initialization to either the constructor or a method that cannot be overriden.